# Isomorphism of $A^{op} \otimes A$ and $End_k(A).$

Tags: abstract-algebra

My professor is trying to show that the map $\phi: A^{op} \otimes A \rightarrow End_k(A)$ is an isomorphism for $A$ a CSA over $k.$ The map is $a \otimes b \mapsto (c \mapsto bca).$ However, is $(c \mapsto bca)$ an endomorphism of $A?$ I see how the map respects scalar multiplication of $k$ and addition, but I cannot see how it respects multiplication as $(bcc'a) \neq (bca)(bc'a).$ Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: $\operatorname{End}_k(A)$ means $k$-linear maps $A \to A$, not algebra homomorphisms $A \to A$.

Comment: I thought it was the set of all endomorphisms, i.e. homomorphisms $A \rightarrow A!$ Why would they call it $End$ then? Does it come from the endomorphism ring of vector spaces which are $k$-linear?

Comment: @伽罗瓦 Most often, the end notation is used with modules in mind, although it would not be illogical to also use it for algebra and ring homomorphisms. In my experience you don't have much cause to talk about those sets though. It's typically sets of module endomorphisms.